# Is 'require(...)' a common javascript pattern or a library function?

Tags: javascript, require

I usually find this as the first line in node.js scripts/modules as well as phantomJS, casperJS etc. I'm curious, if this is a common pattern for server-side javascript (SSJS) (similar to `#include` in C/C++ or `import` in Java) or is it a a library like RequireJS or LabJS that is being called for this inclusion (neither of which I have gotten a chance to use in practice, as yet)?

e.g. `var http = require('http')` or `var casper = require('casper').create()`

I'm curious if this is a pattern that has become *standardized* for SSJS or does every library/tool call an existing function?

Please pardon the *n00b* dimension to the question but I would like to know the 'why' behind its omnipresence :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `require()` idiom is part of a specification known as [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS). Specifically, that part of the spec is called 'Modules'. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is just one implementation of CommonJS (and it's usually a browser-side implementation - in fact, it takes a [different approach](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) because of the asynchronous nature of the browser).

If you look at the list of implementations on the CommonJS site, you'll [see Node.js listed](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Implementations/node.js). Notice that it implements 'Modules'. Hence, that's where it's coming from - it's very much built-in.

Answer (score 8):

The `require` in PhantomJS and Node.js means exactly the same with the difference that none of the base modules match. Although the `fs` module exists for both, they are different and do not provide the same functions.

`require` is functionally the same in PhantomJS and Node.js. CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS and uses its `require` function, but also patches it. With CasperJS it is also possible to require a module with its name such as `require('module')` instead of `require('./module')` if it is in the same directory.

Full matrix (file.js is in the same directory as the executed script):

```
            | node
            |   | phantom
            |   |   | casper
            |   |   |   | slimer
------------+---+---+---+--------
file        | n | n | y | y
./file      | y | y | y | y
file.js     | n | n | n | n
./file.js   | n | n | n | n
```

PhantomJS can also use modules defined in the special folder `node_modules` in the same way that node does. It cannot use actual node modules that have dependencies to modules that are not present in PhantomJS.

### Examples of what can be required:

#### m.js (for functions)

```
module.exports = function(){
    return {
        someKey: [1,2,3,4],
        anotherKey: function(){
            console.log("module exports works");
        }
    }
};
```

#### e.js (for everything else as JS)

```
exports.someKey = {
    innerKey: [1,2,3,4]
};

exports.anotherKey = function(){
    console.log("exports works");
};
```

#### a.json (arbitrary JSON)

```
[
    {
        "someKey": [ 1,2,3,4 ],
        "anotherKey": 3
    }
]
```

#### script.js

```
var m = require("./m")();
m.anotherKey(); // prints "module exports works"

var e = require("./e");
e.anotherKey(); // prints "exports works"

var a = require("./a");
console.log(a[0].anotherKey); // prints "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The others gave nice technical answers, but I wanted to provide a super simplified answer just in case it helps someone in the future. "require" isn't in itself a library, but it's used when you want access modules (libraries and frameworks and such). So it's not like "require" is the most popular library or anything like that :).

By the way, plenty of older code demands that you still use "require" (notice I avoided saying it's required), but new syntax has been developed (I guess with ES6, from 2015) using the word "import." I definitely prefer import, and it is used for the exact same purpose, though it does look a bit different.

Anyways, as the others mentioned, "require" means you are requiring (i.e. accessing) a *module*. But that doesn't necessarily mean that you are getting access to a *library* or *framework*... you might actually be getting access to another page that you yourself created! For example, you might see this:

```
 - var Comment = require("./models/comment");
```

This just means "give me access to that *comment* file I made inside the models directory." This is also considered a module.

So you can think of it like this... you *require* some code (or you *import* it)... so that you can utilize it the way you want. If you didn't require/import it, you wouldn't get it.