# Writing to filesystem from within phantomjs sandboxed environment

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I need to traverse forms on a site and save intermediate results to files. I'm using phantomjs' `page.evaluate`, but I'm having trouble accessing the filesystem from within `page.evaluate`'s sandboxed environment. I have something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<option1.length; i++){
    for (var ii = 0; ii<option2.length; ii++){
        for (var iii = 0; iii<option3.length; iii++){
        ...
            //I found what I want to save
            fs.write("someFileName", someData);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I don't have access to nodejs' `fs` from within `page.evaluate`, so the above does not work. I seem to have a few options:

- Store everything I need to write to an array, and return that from the `page.evaluate` context into the outer, nodejs context, then save it from there. This would require memory I don't have.
- Break up the above logic into smaller `page.evaluate` methods that return singe pieces of data to save to the filesytem.
- Somehow pass into the `page.evaluate` a magic function to write to the filesystem. This seems to not be possible (if I try to pass in a function that calls `fs.writeFile` for example, I get that `fs` is undefined, even if `fs` is a free variable in the function I passed?)
- Return an iterator which, when pulled, yields the next piece of data to be written
- Setup a trivial web server on the localhost that simply accepts POST requests and writes their contents into the filesystem. The `page.evaluate` code would then make those requests to the localhost. I almost try this but I'm not sure I'll be affected by the same-origin policy.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your evaluation is sound, but you forgot one type: [`onCallback`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html). You can register to the event handler in the phantom context and push your data from page context to a file through this callback:

```
page.onCallback = function(data) {
    if (!data.file) {
        data.file = "defaultFilename.txt";
    }
    if (!data.mode) {
        data.mode = "w";
    }
    fs.write(data.file, data.str, data.mode);
};

...
page.evaluate(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i<option1.length; i++){
        for (var ii = 0; ii<option2.length; ii++){
            for (var iii = 0; iii<option3.length; iii++){
            ...
                // save data
                if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
                    window.callPhantom({ file: "someFileName", str: someData, mode: "a" }); // append
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note that PhantomJS does not run in Node.js. Although, there are bridges between Node.js and PhantomJS. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458182).

Comment: I mean, what type of writing stuff to the disk from page context you select is primarily opinion-based. I can just suggest one that might be a good fit for your use case, but might not be good for the next person's use case. Every person should decide for themselves, how they want to do it. I can't say *use this every time*.

Comment: yeah. I think this bridge between Node.js and PhantomJS is mainly what people will get out of your answer.

Comment: Really? I haven't written about any bridges. The code is vanilla PhantomJS. Code for PhantomJS bridge for Node.js will be slightly different.

Comment: Sorry, it was my confusion. I see that PhantomJS doesn't run in Node.js. What I meant was the "bridge" between the `page.evaluate` context and the outer phantomjs context.

Comment: Can I register multiple `onCallback` functions? Or only one?

Comment: Only one, but you should be able to distinguish multiple actions based on the object properties that are passed.