# Cannot call require('fs') with PhantomJS runner

Tags: require, scala.js

I've been trying to use the FS API in PhantomJS, but I get an error I'm not able to understand when I run the following code

```
private[scalajssupport] object PhantomFile {
  val fs: PhantomFS = js.Dynamic.global.require("fs").asInstanceOf[PhantomFS]
}
```

The error I get is:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$g["require"]("fs")')
```

However, when I run

```
var fs = global["require"]("fs")
```

directly in the PhantomJS REPL, it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when using PhantomJS to run scala.js code, it is ran in a sandbox with the "webpage" module, which does not have access to require.

The only way to write to the filesystem was to define a callback in [onCallback](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html), as seen in the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487724/writing-to-filesystem-from-within-phantomjs-sandboxed-environment).