# How to include a file content in a casper test file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs

I have a typical casper test file and a file containing constants I would like to use in the casper test file, how can I include the constant file in the casper test file?

For example, the constant file contains:

```
var ERR_XXX=1000;
var ERR_YYY=1001;
```

and the casper test file contains:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.test.begin("Open Unexisting Page", function(test) {

    casper.start("https://localhost/xxx.html",
        function() {
            this.test.assertHttpStatus(404, 'HTTP status is 404 for ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
        });

   casper.run(function() {test.done();});

});
```

I would like to be able to call `console.log("Some error:" + ERR_XXX)` in the casper file. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`read`](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/read.html) the constants file using the [file system module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) of PhantomJS and [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it immediately to make the variables known to the following code.

But I would suggest that you write your file as JSON

```
{
    "ERR_XXX": 1000,
    "ERR_YYY": 1001
}
```

and simply `require` that JSON file:

```
var c = require("const.json");
console.log(c.ERR_XXX);
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458182) for more information.