# How to Include Coffeescript File in one more coffeescript file

Tags: coffeescript, casperjs

I want to use code written in one.coffee file in one more coffee file two.coffee , just like include function present in Php

I am working on casperjs with coffee script

Comment: `require` is also available in coffeescript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is 'require(...)' a common javascript pattern or a library function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551861/is-require-a-common-javascript-pattern-or-a-library-function)

Comment: So should I use it like file=require('B.coffee')

Comment: I don't know. Try `require('B.coffee')`, `require('B')` and `require('./B')`

Comment: Thanks Artjom B  its working , but how to use it with casperjs , i have my  casperjs code in B.coffee file

Comment: I don't understand. If it's working, then you are already using it with CasperJS, don't you? Can you describe what your problem is exactly?